# How to start Appium server programatically in mac using ruby ?

Tags: appium

Is there a way I can get appium to startup within the code? I am trying to automate an iOS application, Since appium only needs to run when my test is running it doesnt make sense to me to keep the appium server always going.

Right now I am using Appium GUI to start server.Is it possible to add something in Before method to start the appium server before connecting the WebDriver to it, and then terminating it in the After method.

Please help me to do it in Mac using Ruby.

Appium server version: 1.8.0 
Mac OS: 10.13 
node: 6.11 
Ruby: 2.5.1

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for BDD framework written Ruby. Paste these two hooks in hooks.rb file

**Starting the server:**

```
AfterConfiguration do |config|
pid = spawn ‘appium --address 0.0.0.0 --port 4723’
Process.detach(pid)
sleep(10)
end
```

AfterConfiguration hook that will be run after Cucumber has been configured. This hook will run only once,after support has been loaded but before features are loaded. so it is usefull to launch Appium server.

**Stoping the server:**

```
at_exit do
exec ‘/usr/bin/killall -KILL node’
end
```

at_exit will be executed after execution of all the feature files. So executing `exec '/usr/bin/killall -KILL node'` command inside this hook kills the server at the end

Comment: I am getting following error:
No such file or directory - appium (Errno::ENOENT)
No matching processes belonging to you were found

Answer (score 0):

call shell commands from inside of a Ruby program.

```
`/Applications/Appium.app/Contents/Resources/node_modules/appium/bin/appium.js --address 127.0.0.1 --chromedriver-port 9516 --bootstrap-port 4725 --selendroid-port 8082 --no-reset --local-timezone`
```

change the path accordingly or copy the appium app to Applications folder

Comment: Thanks for your answer joe.

Comment: AfterConfiguration do
  exec 'appium'
 end .   I added this in hooks file. Appium is starting but feature file is not executing after that